# What is the celery task distribution algorithm?

Tags: celery

What is the algorithm used to distribute the task load between workers in celery?
I checked the documentation, could not find the info.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the broker that is used.  For example, for redis, each of worker process uses kombu's redis transport which in turn calls [`brpop` to get the next task available](https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/stable/_modules/kombu/transport/redis.html#Channel.basic_consume).  [redis implements `brpop`](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) using the longest-waiting client algorithm to allocate a certain task to a certain client (waiting celery worker process).